# Code Beautification with angular-ui-codemirror with indention

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, codemirror

I generated xml code with jquery by using following code,

```js
var _outerBlock = $("<outerBlock>");
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var _innerBlock = $("<innerBlock>Serial " + i + "</innerBlock>")
  _outerBlock.append(_innerBlock)
}
var _tmp = $("<div>");
var $output = _tmp.html();
```

Now I am getting one line xml code in $output variable. I tried using codemirror.js to beautify this code, its applying styling but it is not adding indention.

Here What I tried from browser console with plain codemirror.js

```
var myCodeMirror = CodeMirror(document.body, {
  value: code,
  mode:  "text/html",
  lineNumbers:true
});
```

How Can I use indention? How can I display code with angular-ui-codemirror?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For correct xml syntax indentation you need to include

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
```

*(path to xml mode js file may be different, but you anyways need such defined..)*

Then you use it like:

```
config = {
    mode : "xml",
    htmlMode: true,
    // ...
};
```

..and in angular you append ui-codemirror to what ever element you need.

In angular, setup is given though differently:

```
myAppModule.controller('MyController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
$scope.editorOptions = {
    lineWrapping : true,
    lineNumbers: true,
    readOnly: 'nocursor',
    mode: 'xml',
};
```

}]);

.. And

```
<ui-codemirror ui-codemirror-opts="editorOptions"></ui-codemirror>
```

**Sources / further reading:**

https://libraries.io/bower/angular-sdco-tools

[CodeMirror HTML mode not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17622750/codemirror-html-mode-not-working)

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror/blob/master/README.md