# How to use html mode in codemirror?

Tags: codemirror

How to use html mode in codemirror? I tried but it did not work. Please write full code to demonstrate how to use html mode in codemirror and how to highlight the code. Thanks...

Comment: Welcome to SO. **We are here to help you troubleshoot or help you in the codes you provide.** Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) on how to post questions.

Comment: have you check [https://stackoverflow.com/q/17622750/1950896](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17622750/1950896)